# Vinyl Crackling Effect

Tags: filters, audio, distortion

I want to know how can I achieve this effect:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQg9M_47c3A

Do I need to use a filter? And what can I use for the crackling, poping effect?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Several approaches exist to create a vinyl crackle effect [1]. Usually, this type of disturbance is assumed to be an additive one. Hence, the crackling effect is achieved by somehow generating/obtaining a disturbance signal and adding it to the clean signal, not by filtering the original signal.

If you just want to get hold of such crackle signal, you can find at least one generator online, for example [here](http://mynoise.net/NoiseMachines/dustyScratchedVinylNoiseGenerator.php). If you don't mind to pay money for software that can simulate not only vinyl disturbances but a variety of effects, have a look at [iZotope Trash 2](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/effects-instruments/trash/). (This company used to offer a vinyl sound generator called "Vinyl" for free, but unfortunately this is discontinued.)

Furthermore, there are a number of free samples online (e.g. at [freesound.org](http://www.freesound.org)) that can be used.

If, on the other hand, you're interested in generating a plausible sounding but artificial vinyl click/crackle signal on your own, I would recommend having a look at an [article](http://research.spa.aalto.fi/publications/papers/antiquing/) by Välimäki et al., describing, among other things, how to do this.

[1] S. V. Vaseghi, Advanced Digital Signal Processing and Noise Reduction. Chichester, West Sussex: Wiley, 2008.